# How much star anise should I add to a stew?

Tags: ingredient-selection

I’m making a stew with about 700 grams of meat and it will have a lower rather than higher amount of water.  I will be using star anise for first time and I hear a little bit can over power the whole stew so you should start small.

I’m guessing with a stew you should add the whole star rather than ground powder?  How many stars would be ok to begin with considering the ingredients above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Star anise is fairly potent.  For me, it is in the same category as cloves, in terms of potency.  I would use one "star" for starters.  Adjust from there.

Comment: You can break a star anise into smaller pieces and add part of a star, it may be better to do that first.

Answer (score 0):

My mother usually puts five or seven when cooking, but as far as I'm concerned, its taste is a little unacceptable.

Comment: I think your mother has either very weak star anise or very flavorsome other ingredients, I use one to three parts of one star and it is already a strong flavor.